# Is there a WatchKit sensor API?

Tags: iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

Is there any API available for Apple Watch Kit sensors such as the accelerometer, heart rate monitor, haptic sensor ?

How can I access those sensors ?

Answer (score 5):

Sensor Data (accelerometer, heart rate monitor, haptic sensor) information is **now available** in `Watchkit for watchOS 2.0`.

You could check this information in the following session which is total 30 minutes presentation.If you do not want to watch entire session, then you directly jump to the `CoreMotion` and `HealthKit` features which is in between 22-28 min:

[**WatchKit for watchOS 2.0 Session in WWDC 2015**](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=105)

**Heart Rate Code**

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKWorkout_Class/

**Accelerometer code**

Here is the implementation of Accelerometer in WatchKit Extension, I have added three labels (`LabelX`, `LabelY`, and `LabelZ`) on watch storyboard.

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreMotion

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {


    @IBOutlet weak var labelX: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelY: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelZ: WKInterfaceLabel!
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()


    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

        if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true) {
            let handler:CMAccelerometerHandler = {(data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                self.labelX.setText(String(format: "%.2f", data!.acceleration.x))
                self.labelY.setText(String(format: "%.2f", data!.acceleration.y))
                self.labelZ.setText(String(format: "%.2f", data!.acceleration.z))
            }
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: handler)
        }
        else {
            self.labelX.setText("not available")
            self.labelY.setText("not available")
            self.labelZ.setText("not available")
        }
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        super.didDeactivate()

        motionManager.stopAccelerometerUpdates()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no current available option to access any sensor of the Apple Watch with the current version of the WatchKit SDK.